# YouTube - Link Asset ID to Video ID

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to get an asset's video ID from the asset ID in YouTube?
I am writing a Javascript application that will allow a user to input the asset ID (Content ID API) and retrieve that asset's views, gross revenue, monetized views (YT Analytics API).

Is there any way to link the two?  If I could return the video ID from the Asset ID then I would be set but I can't see where I can get that in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim is where videoId, assetId, and contentManagerId all linked.

You can do a [claimSearch->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claimSearch/list) with [assetId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claimSearch/list#assetId) and get [videoId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claimSearch#videoId) in response.

Note that this will only list "your own or your managed channel's" claims. You can not search other people's claims.